# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at __webpack_require__ (main.js:64)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have React in frotend and Django in backend. Everything was working fine but after I gone through its files , then suddenly the error comes up.

I hope I did not change any files or codes, but how come this strange error occure ?

Please refer to the attached screenshot.

this error looks strange, the same codes work well 7 months before and it's running well in production mode till now, when I give the command `npm run dev` it causes error now

https://github.com/Anoop-George/Fully-functional-ecommerce/blob/master/frontend/src/components/appbar.js

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this error looks strange, the same codes work well 7 months before and its running well in production mode, when I give command npm run dev it causes error now

Comment: If something was working 7 months ago, it is possible that it will break today. Because dependencies might upgrade. Try deleting *node_modules*, *package-lock.json* file and do the installation again. There should be an error in *SearchAppBar* component. But I can't tell unless I see the code in that component.

Comment: Thanks you, the code follows https://github.com/Anoop-George/Fully-functional-ecommerce/blob/master/frontend/src/components/appbar.js

Comment: Thank you I understand your point,  Hope you are doing well, I remember that you had helped me long before.

Comment: I did : `npm i && npm run dev`. No error. How do I see the app in browser? Which port does it run on?

Comment: The port is http://localhost:8000/ but npm make modules and hooked with Django template, for me also there is no error in compiling but when its in the browser the error comes